# Is there a quick way to see that this function is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $f,g: [0,1] \to X$ be a continuous function ($[0,1]$ has the subspace topology), where $X$ is an
>   arbitrary topological space.
>
> Define $h: [0,1] \to X: t \mapsto \begin{cases}f(2t) \quad0 \leq t
>  \leq 1/2 \\g(2t-1) \quad 1/2 \leq t \leq 1\end{cases}$
>
> How can I quickly verify that $h$ is continuous?

EDIT: It must be the case that $f(1) = g(0)$, by definition of $h$

I cannot use limits, as these are metric space concepts and $X$ is not necessarily metrizable.

Comment: Why would $h$ be continuous? Let $X$ be $\mathbb R$, let $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ and let $g(x)=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Note that $f(1) = g(0)$ is asked, by definition of $h$.

Comment: I see. You are implying that by defining them both at $t=\frac{1}{2}$. It may be better style by making that explicit.

Comment: I only realised after your remark. Thanks.

Comment: Limits of a function can be defined in a  topological space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t\rightarrow 2t$ is continuous for $0\leq t\leq 1/2$, and $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, then the composition $\varphi_{1}$ is continuous on $[0,1/2]$.

Similar reasoning is valid for $\varphi_{2}(t)=g(2t-1)$ on $[1/2,1]$.

$f$ is well-defined at $t=1/2$, and $[0,1/2],[1/2,1]$ are closed, by Gluing Lemma, $h$ is continuous:

\begin{align*}
h^{-1}(F)&=\{t\in[0,1/2]: f(2t)\in F\}\cup\{t\in[1/2,1]: g(2t-1)\in F\}\\
&=\varphi_{1}^{-1}(F)\cup\varphi_{2}^{-1}(F)
\end{align*}
for closed sets $F$. Note that $\varphi_{1}^{-1}(F),\varphi_{2}^{-1}(F)$ are closed in $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$ respectively, and hence closed in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks. The "Gluing Lemma" was what I was looking for.